# Allowing multiple declarations of data constructors

Tags: haskell

I am currently experimenting with data types and I've ran into an issue involving multiple declarations of data constructors.

```
data DBPosition = Unknown
                | Omega Integer
                | Delta Integer
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data DBGeometry = Unknown | Cis | Trans
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data DoubleBond = DoubleBond DBPosition DBGeometry
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

If I was to make a value such as - `let bond = DoubleBond Unknown Unknown`, then it could be inferred that the first `Unknown` has a type of `DBPosition` while the second `Unknown` has a type of `DBPosition`. Unfortunately this is not the case:

```
test.hs:6:27:
Multiple declarations of `Unknown'
Declared at: test.hs:1:27
             test.hs:6:27
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Are there any language extensions that can be used to get around this?

Comment: Off-topic: as a lapsed chemist, my eyes gleamed when I realised what you are defining :)

Comment: the Problem is not with `DoubleBond` it's that you have two constructors with the same name - if you just would write `x = Unknown` what should the type of `x` be? - IMO just write `UnknownPosition` and `UnknownGeometry` and you are fine ;) // PS: if you really want to do this you can still move the definitions in different modules

Comment: I agree, but you could get around that issue by writing x = Unknown :: DBPosition.

Comment: You could simply remove `Unknown` from the constructors and use the `Maybe` type: `data DoubleBond = DoubleBond (Maybe DBPosition) (Maybe DBGeometry); data DBGeometry = Cis | Trans`. Then you can write `DoubleBond Nothing Nothing`. If you really want to use the word `Unknown`, simply define your own `Maybe` type.

Comment: @MichaelT That wouldn't work. Being specified (digression: is there a better word to use when talking about the relation between parameter-less constructors and the corresponding values?) through a constructor means that `Unknown` can have just one type. You *might* achieve a similar effect with a type class, but I strongly recommend against it -- it really, really isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 10):

As Carsten pointed out above, your definition does not work because you have two constructors with the same name. You'd need to use e.g. `UnknownDBPosition` and `UnknownDBGeometry`. However, I'd argue a better solution arises from recognising:

- That the concept of an unknown value works in precisely the same way no matter if you are talking about double bond positions, geometries, or whatever else; and
- That `Unknown` is not actually a variety of double bond geometry or position.

That being so, I recommend that you remove both `Unknown` and use `Maybe` to specify lack of knowledge.

```
data DBPosition = Omega Integer
                | Delta Integer
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data DBGeometry = Cis | Trans
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data DoubleBond = DoubleBond (Maybe DBPosition) (Maybe DBGeometry)
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is similar the approach I have used so far instead I made the type `Identity a = Unknown | Known a`. This is essentially the same as `Maybe` so perhaps it I should just use `Maybe` to avoid duplicating the same functionality.

Comment: @MichaelT, yes I recommend it.  There are many useful functions defined for working with `Maybe`s in [`Data.Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) -- I find the few that relate `Maybe`s to lists to be especially useful.

Comment: @MichaelT, using `Maybe` will save time and make it easier for others to understand your code. Also, `Identity` would be assumed by most Haskellers to refer to `Data.Functor.Identity.Identity`, defined as `newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}`, a fairly popular type.

Comment: `Maybe` is an instance of some pretty useful things like `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Alternative`, `Monad`, and `Traversable`.