# Maybe as part of a Haskell datatype

Tags: haskell, types, option-type

Say we want to model someones health. The person can be either sick and have the `Flu`, a `Cold`, an `Allergy` or be `Healthy`. There are a number of ways we could define this in Haskell, two of them being:

```
data Condition = Flu | Cold | Allergy | Healthy
```

or

```
data Condition = Flu | Cold | Allergy
data Sickness  = Sickness (Maybe Condition)
```

This is similar to defining a `Tree` structure, since the `Tree` element can either be a `Node` with 2 `Tree`s or `Empty`:

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty
```

Or the `Tree` could also be defined using a `Maybe`:

```
data Node a = Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
data Tree a = Tree (Maybe (Node a))
```

Each choice has its pros and cons. Without using a `Maybe`, we capture all of the possible values of a `Tree` or `Health` in a single data declaration, so the scope is very clear. On the other hand, if we do use a `Mayb`e, then we capture the essence that something might or might not be present in the data model and avoid creating nothingness-defining datatypes like `Empty` or `Healthy` and just use `Nothing` to model the absence. This simplifies the model a little bit, but the declaration of the datatype(s) is no longer contained in a single piece of code.

What are other advantages and drawbacks to either approach?

Comment: Nit picking: you're not actually using the `Maybe` type in your code. The word `Maybe` in the phrase `data Sickness = Maybe Condition` defines a _value constructor_ called `Maybe`, which happens to share the name of the _type constructor_ called `Maybe` purely by coincidence. (Types and values live in different namespaces in Haskell.) I suspect you meant `data Sickness = Sickness (Maybe Condition)`, which defines a value constructor called `Sickness` with a parameter of type `Maybe Condition`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Yes, thanks! Edits made.

Comment: More nitpicking: I would tweak Benjamin's suggestion by swapping the names of `Sickness` and `Condition` (i.e. `data Condition = Condition (Maybe Sickness)`).

Comment: This isn't a concrete programming question, it's a discussion question. If you actually come aross a situation where this comes up in real code you can try heading over to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, as some people point out, any answer given is subjective to some degree. Code is, however, more than a way to make a computer perform computations - it's also a medium of communication.

The clearer you can communicate your intent to the people reading the code in the future, the better you address that concern. To take a cue from [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020)

> Explicit is better than implicit

That heuristic has served me well in many different programming languages and scenarios. A corollary is that in object-oriented programming, one should [favour explicit domain objects over primitive obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling).

I'd be inclined to apply a like rule of thumb in cases like the OP, and favour explicitly named types if they better communicate intent.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a large part of the decision hinges on how *meaningful* you consider `Healthy` as a condition. If the answer is "not very much", you are probably better off with something like the `Maybe` encoding (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32389885/2751851) for discussion of a more clear-cut case). By the way, if the illnesses weren't mutually exclusive and there were other factors contributing to a condition, we would have to adopt a somewhat different encoding:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Set (Set)

data Sickness = Flu | Cold | Allergy
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Alertness = Sleepy | Distracted | Caffeinated
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Condition = Condition (Set Sickness) (Set Alertness)
```

I feel that in such a scenario having `Healthy` as a separate kind of condition would make significantly less sense.

Back to your original formulation, it is worth mentioning there is an intermediate third option: rolling your own specialised, domain-specific `Maybe` (cf. [Mark Seeman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49718466/2751851)):

```
data Sickness = Flu | Cold | Allergy

data Condition = Healthy | Sick Sickness
```

By doing that, you will miss out on the `Maybe`-handling tools, and you might have to provide some instances and functions yourself if you want to use them (though that might be a non-issue depending on how you plan to use `Condition`).